# Python - Can't import Pysal

Tags: python, pandas, dbf, pysal

I am using Pycharm in Windows 10, and I need to import Pysal to make some data transformations using DBF files with Pandas.

For that I have:

```
import pysal as ps
import pandas as pd
db = ps.open(dbfile) #Pysal to open DBF
d = {col: dbfile.by_col(col) for col in dbfile.header}
```

I have to install pysal packages but when I run "`pip install pysal`" I got the following error:

```
    raise OSError("could not find or load %s" % lib_name)
    OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-32.dll
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How I can install pysal on my environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is to download it from Christoph Gohlke's [site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pysal). You can install the whl file in your virtual environment by running

`pip install [path to the whl file]`

in your pycharm terminal.

Comment: I've tried that but:
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of \AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9xmwwwwo

Comment: forgive me if I'm being rude, but did you give the full path of the whl file. Up intill the .whl extension? Because it worked for me.

Comment: Nipun, yes I am passing the complete path but I'm getting this error:
ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.